# Compare 2 strings with different encoding

Tags: php

How to make the following strings equal:

```
$str1 = "Première &eacute;quation";
$str2 = "Première équation";
```

I tried *html_entity_decode($str1)* but it doesn't work

Comment: did you try `htmlentities`? http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php - it'd be on `$str2`

Comment: `html_entity_decode($str1)` is works for me. `var_dump($str2 == html_entity_decode($str1));` shows me `true`.

Comment: I tried comparing html_entity_decode($str1) == $str2 and it return true.

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoMartínezGadea
@lolka_bolka
`$str1 = "Première &eacute;quation";
$str2 = "Première équation"; 

var_dump($str2 == html_entity_decode($str1));`
returns bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a combination of [`strcmp`](https://www.php.net/strcmp) and [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/html_entity_decode) for binary-safe comparison.

```
<?php

$str1 = "Première &eacute;quation";
$str2 = "Première équation"; 

var_dump( strcmp(html_entity_decode($str1), $str2) );
```

https://eval.in/551298

For example;

```
// Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.
if( strcmp(html_entity_decode($str1), $str2) === 0 ) {
   echo "They match";
}
```

Comment: I wonder why the OP says "I tried html_entity_decode($str1) but it doesn't work"? Maybe the issue was the string comparison...

Comment: when i try this 
`$str1 = "Première &eacute;quation";
$str2 = "Première équation"; 
var_dump( strcmp(html_entity_decode($str1), $str2) );`
it returns int(38)

Comment: I'm assuming these are hardcoded strings? What's the character encoding?

Comment: I dont know about encoding. but when I test the code from a localhost it works. the problem occur while testing on my remote server.

Comment: phpinfo() show me this :
`default_charset = no value`
Should I change it ?